# How should I analyze proportional community data, in respect to habitat variables?

Tags: ecology, statistics, community-ecology, limnology, habitat

I want to analyze how the proportions of groups of species in a biological community correlated to habitat variables. I have 6 functional groups, defined by their similar traits, and I want to know how their proportions vary dependent upon changes in habitat size, and time since the changes started to occur (e.g. ramp disturbances).

I basically want to be able to say, "Group A species contributed more to the community makeup / function as habitat decreased. Group B species decreased in proportion, but not nearly as fast as Group C, which were extirpated by the time only 20% of the habitat remained" with some kind of stats to back it up.

I also monitored the communities as they recovered from the distrubance, and would similarly like to make inferences about which groups were contributing more early on vs. late stages recovery (e.g. could species with D-group traits be better at reestablishing?)

I don't think using raw abundance is appropriate because (generally) all groups decrease in abundance as habitat decreases, but some groups actually dramatically increase in proportion of the community, and thus would contribute more to the ecosystem services etc. etc.

Does anyone know how I should analyze this data? I have thought about using Spearman correlations to answer broadly if the groups do correlate with habitat changes, but this cant really tell me if one group is increasing or decreasing at a faster rate.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: What form are your observations in? Counts? Are they somewhat sporadic (like sightings of animals) or more systematic (like counts of plants within a grid)? How are observations structured over time and space? Are you measuring multiple habitats, or a single habitat over time?

Comment: I would say they're more sporadic, but we tried to make it as systematic as possible so samples could be compared. It was a timed-search method, using kick netting in streams to catch macroinvertebrates. We got roughly 1,000 - 10,000 individuals in each sample, and about 70ish species in total. Which were grouped via traits into those 6 groups.

Comment: Interesting... I'd highly recommend collaborating with a statistician with some experience in your domain. Proportions don't seem quite right, because it's probably not meaningful to consider individuals as equivalent/exchangeable, but you probably need some sort of control for the "sample size". I thought I'd have some suggestions, but I'm afraid this will quickly get beyond the scope of a StackExchange answer.

Comment: Sound like you want to do some compositional analyses of relative abundance data. It's a common approach used in microbial community analysis based on metagenomic sequencing data, but that's because the absolute count data is an experimental artifact from the sequencing methods and not necessarily reflective of absolute abundances in the samples.

Comment: Highly recommended read: **McCune, B. and Grace, J.B., 2002. *Analysis of Ecological Communities*. MjM Software Design: Gleneden Beach. ISBN 0-9721290-0-6. 300 pp.**. You might find a lot of interest in distance-based analyses (see "bray-curtis distance" for your abundance data), ordinations, and literally a whole host of multivariate analyses. Keeping track of temporal autocorrelations will also likely play an important role in your analyses.

Comment: I don't have complete grasp of the scope of your study/questions based on what you've presented here , and -- perhaps I'll be honest -- that type of statistical consulting advice is outside the scope of *this* site. If you already knew what you wanted to do or could more narrowly describe your question/analysis, some of us would certainly try to help. But I think at this stage -- especially given the complexity of your system -- I, like Bryan, recommend speaking more thoroughly with a dedicated statistician to ensure you're adequately covering all your bases and making the best decision.

Comment: Also, you're essentially asking multiple questions that each would require its own analysis approach. You might find a role of ordinations, mantel tests, structural equation modeling, etc for your 1st question, while MRPPs (multi-response permutation procedures), partial mantel tests, and mixed-effects models might play roles in other parts of your analysis. I guess I'll end by saying that your post is currently too broad and underdeveloped for our site. But again, I hope some of these comments steer you in the right direction. Read McCune & Grace (2002) and talk to a statistician. Good luck!